# Keyboard not hidden when starting a comment and then hitting the back button

Tags: bug, android-app

Just noticed a bug on the Android app. I started a comment, then instead of hitting the downward chevron to cancel the comment, I pressed the back button in the top left corner. The screen navigated back, but the keyboard remained open. Using the standard Google keyboard (gboard). Let me know if you need more details.

Attached image. Note that the spelling suggestions bar disappears too.

[image: Screenshot showing keyboard opened]

- App Version: 1.0.94
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G935W8

  - OS Version: 7.0 (G935W8VLU2BQE5)

Comment: Reproduced in app `1.0.95` too.

Comment: Hmm.. not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 7.1.2 (LineageOS), SE app v1.0.95, using Gboard keyboard... Both downward Chevron and top-left button closes the keyboard.